# Backbone.js Click Event Won't Fire

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-views

I have been trying to learn backbone.js, but I can't figure out why my click event isn't firing when I click the home link.  I'm fairly new to backbone and I'm just not sure what am I missing? I've looked up a bunch of different tutorials on the net, but can't seem to find the lose hole.  Please help!

Backbone.js

```
    var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('.content'),

        events:{
            "click #home": "animateNavigation"
        },
        initialize: function(){
            _.bindAll(this, 'displayTrips'); 

            // Add the model collections
            this.collection = new ModelList();
            this.collection.bind('add', this.displayTrips); // Collection event binder
        },
        animateNavigation: function(){
            alert('test');

            return false;
        },
        displayTrips: function(params){
            var items = params.get('data');
        }
    });

    var home_view = new HomeView();
```

HTML

```
<div class="content">
     <div class="left">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="nav_arrow"></div>                   
                <a href="home" class="active" id="home">
                    <img alt="Home" src="/assets/img/nav/left/star.png">
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="tropical" id="tropical">
                    <img alt="Tropical" src="/assets/img/nav/left/fins_grey.png">
                    <span>Tropical</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're finding the element at the time the model is declared.   If you have your script in the header or anywhere before this content, that element doesn't exist yet.  I don't know that there should be any good reason to use `$('.content')` here anyway, just use `'.content'`

Edit: Well, I see you are also declaring a new instance of your view as well. I don't know if that line represents literally what you have in your script, or you just put it there for the purpose of demonstrating your basic use. I generally define the views and models elsewhere from the page logic (which would have the instances of those things), primarily so that I can reuse them.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add

```
console.log(home_view.$el.html());
```

at the end, to check the Dom Element of home_view please. I assume that something goes wrong when binding the view to the Dom element.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solved it for me:

`var home_view = new HomeView({el:$('.content')});`

UPDATE - better than that, do this:

`var home_view = new HomeView({el:'.content'});`

then `this.$el` will work as the above post says